# Deserializing Issue in Entity Framework 4.0 

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-4

I am working on an appliction, using Entity Framework 4.0. and WCF.

I am returning list of objects say (Employees)

and the navigational property of that object is say(Departments)

and Department has further a navigational property (Branch)

I am including everything as

```
Employees.include("Departments.Branch");
```

Now th issue all those departments whose Branch is same, is set to null(except the first one) upon deserializing on WCF.

I need to use the branch for some binding purposes, kindly guide me how should i get rid of this problem.

This is the screenshot of the entities [image]

Comment: Dou you use Self-Tracking Entities?

Comment: No, these are normal POCO entities

Comment: If you profile it on server side what would be the output ? is it having correct values?

Comment: Yes, on server side, this shows exactly what i am expectin

Comment: How do you return these entities?
and what if you try to access them just before deserializing, do you find them working fine or what?

Comment: and kindly, post some code so we may help you better.
also tell us what version of EF are you using?

Comment: Can you post the code for Department and Branch classes?

Comment: I have added the screenshot for the entitites, kindly look at it

Answer (score 3):

It may be that the data is not being loaded before serialisation, but when you debug on the server side, lazy loading causes the data to be loaded.

A couple of things that you could try.

This will force the query to run:

```
Employees.include("Departments.Branch").ToList();
```

This will explicitly load the entities:

```
context.Entry(Employees).Reference(u => u.Departments.Branch).Load();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use Entity Framework profiler and see whether generated query is having valid data. http://efprof.com/

Comment: This happens only upon deserializing, so nothing a profiler could do for me.

Comment: Ok. Then try to define Data Member with given names and Order of them with attributes, as you have deserialization issue.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx)

> Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) cannot directly serialize or deserialize proxies because the DataContractSerializer can only serialize and deserialize known types, and proxy types are not known types. When you need to serialize POCO entities, disable proxy creation or use the ProxyDataContractResolver class to serialize proxy objects as the original POCO entities. To disable proxy creation, set the ProxyCreationEnabled property to false.

Beyond that, check if you are using [Interoperable Object References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656708.aspx)? I would try that as well. Follow the instructions [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/03/26/561188.aspx) on how to set it up

Answer (score 0):

On your POCO classes + enumerations and structs (all of them that are serialized), you must have the DataContract attribute with IsReference=true:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Employee", Namespace = "http://MyNamespace", IsReference=true)]
class Employee
{
    [DataMember(Name="Branch")]
    public Branch _branch = new Branch();
            ... or ...
    [DataMember(Name="Branches")]
    public List<Branch> _branches = new List<Branch>();
}

[DataContract(Name = "Branch", Namespace = "http://MyNamespace", IsReference=true)]
class Branch { ... }
```

It is the IsReference=true that makes sure that all of the pointers are converted into references during serialization.  Also make sure your references have a DataMember attribute.

Comment: Both attributes are implemented, DataContract and DataMember, there are hundreds of poco classes involved, all works fine, this is the only place where i am getting this issue.

Comment: Just to confirm, the DataContract is using IsReference=true?

Comment: Yes, these two attributes are on my class  [Serializable]
    [DataContract(IsReference=true)]

Comment: Maybe this is too simplistic, but have you looked at the results of Employees.include("Departments.Branch") before serialization and verified that all of the pointers are in place?

Comment: yes, i've verified it several times, before serialization it has all the data, but afterwards similar object of Branches are set to null

Answer (score 0):

On the POCO-Classes use `[DataContract]` for the class, `[DataMember]` for properties, like *Bahri Gungor* said. In addition you can write some Methods, which will be called by the Serializer. Check MSDN for: [OnDeserialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx) [OnDeserializing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.proxydatacontractresolver.aspx), [OnSerialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializedattribute.aspx) and [OnSerializing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializingattribute.aspx)

In WCF-Service you need to use a Attribute, to declare, where you want to return EF-Proxy-Classes.

```
[ApplyDataContractResolver]
public POCO_CLASS GetById(int id){
    // your code here...
}
```

And the ApplyDataContractResolver looks like:

```
public class ApplyDataContractResolverAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior {
    public ApplyDataContractResolverAttribute() {
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription description, BindingParameterCollection parameters) {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription description, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientOperation proxy) {
        var dataContractSerializerOperationBehavior = description.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
        dataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.DataContractResolver = new ProxyDataContractResolver();
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription description, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperation dispatch) {
        var dataContractSerializerOperationBehavior = description.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
        dataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.DataContractResolver = new ProxyDataContractResolver();
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription description) {
        // Do validation.
    }
}
```

Background is that the WCF serialise with an `DataContractSerializer` and EF builds Proxy-Classes to track the changes.

Here a link to MSDN for `ProxyDataContractResolver`: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.proxydatacontractresolver.aspx)

Comment: I have a very large application, which is very working completly fine with WCF and EF, i am using [DataContract] attribute on my PoCo class. and all other things are working completly fine, this is the only exceptional scenario where i am getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use both `.Include()` on the query to load related objects and the `[Include]` attribute in the metadata to allow those related objects to be serialized and sent to the client.

This issue (or at least similar) is discussed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705457.aspx)

Comment: I am using include in the query and event explicitly execute it by using ToList() but that didn't help.